# Running an SSIS 2008R2 Package from a SQL Server 2012 Job

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssis-2012, ssis-2008

I have an SSIS Package that was created in SQL Server 2008 R2. When I attempt to execute the package using the SQL Server 2008 R2 execute package utility, I receive no errors. When I try the same with the SQL Server 2012 execute package utility, I get these errors:

> Error: To run a SSIS package outside of SQL Server Data Tools you 
>   must install Derived Column of Integration Services or higher.
>
> Error: To run a SSIS package outside of SQL Server Data Tools you 
>   must install Conditional Split of Integration Serivces or higher.
>
> Error: To run a SSIS package outisde of SQL Server Data Tools you 
>   must install SSIS Log Provider For SQL Server of Integration Services 
>   or higher.
>
> --****

When I attempt to run the package with a SQL Server 2012 Job, I receive this error:

> Executed as user: NT Service\SQLSERVERAGENT. Microsoft (R) SQL Server
>   Execute Package Utility  Version 11.0.2100.60 for 32-bit  Copyright
>   (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.    Started:  10:20:56
>   AM  Error: 2016-08-31 10:20:56.22     Code: 0xC0011007     Source:
>   {F21F6C0C-91E9-4444-B3C2-8BD4670D8953}      Description: Unable to
>   load the package as XML because of package does not have a valid XML
>   format. A specific XML parser error will be posted.  End Error  Error:
>   2016-08-31 10:20:56.22     Code: 0xC0011002     Source:
>   {F21F6C0C-91E9-4444-B3C2-8BD4670D8953}      Description: Failed to
>   open package file "C:\IHA\IHA_HOSPF105.dtsx" due to error 0x80070005
>   "Access is denied.".  This occurs when loading a package and the file
>   cannot be opened or loaded correctly into the XML document. This can
>   be the result of specifying an incorrect file name when calling
>   LoadPackage or the specified XML file has an incorrect format.  End
>   Error  Could not load package "C:\IHA\IHA_HOSPF105.dtsx" because of
>   error 0xC0011002.  Description: Failed to open package file
>   "C:\IHA\IHA_HOSPF105.dtsx" due to error 0x80070005 "Access is
>   denied.".  This occurs when loading a package and the file cannot be
>   opened or loaded correctly into the XML document. This can be the
>   result of specifying an incorrect file name when calling LoadPackage
>   or the specified XML file has an incorrect format.  Source:
>   {F21F6C0C-91E9-4444-B3C2-8BD4670D8953}  Started:  10:20:56 AM 
>   Finished: 10:20:56 AM  Elapsed:  0.016 seconds.  The package could not
>   be found.  The step failed.

Is it possible to configure the SQL Server Job to point to the SQL Server 2008 R2 execute package utility? In the 'steps' section of the Job, is there a way that I can change the 'Command Line' to do this?

Also, I noticed that the machine I am running the Jobs/packages from has the `SQL Server Integration Services 10.0` service installed. I don't see version `11.0`. If I had that, I would assume that this would also correct the problem. Is that the case?

Comment: Did you convert your IS project to 2012? or Are you just trying to run it on 2012 job?

Comment: To be clear, the 2008 package is on a 2008 SSIS Server, but the SQL Agent job is on a separate server that is SQL 2012?   Why can't you just create the job on the 2008 server?   That's what we do.

Comment: The SQL Server is a 2012 server, but the package was created in BIDS 2008R2. The project has not been converted to 2012.

Comment: There are two version of DTExecUI.exe on the machine. One is the 2008R2 version: "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE\DTExecUI.exe".

2012: "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\DTExecUI.exe". I think this is the version that the 2012 SQL Server Job uses, and it fails to run the SSIS package. 

Can the Job be configured to point to the 2008R2 version of DTExecUI.exe instead of the default 2012 version?